# What is the most elegant way to get a diagram showing elimination method to solve simultaneous equations?

Tags: math-mode

First of all, I show you my effort as follows. It seems to be too complicated in coding with unsatisfied output.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$
    \begin{aligned}
        \!
        \begin{aligned}
            3x +2y &=7 \\
            9x +8y &=22 
        \end{aligned}
        \left|
        \!
        \begin{aligned}
            \times 3\\
            \times 1
        \end{aligned}
        \right|
        &\!
        \begin{aligned}
            9x +6y &=21 \\
            9x +8y &=22 
        \end{aligned}\\
        &\!
        \begin{aligned}
            -2y &=-1 \\
                y &=1/2 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want to achieve are

- The coding must use as minimal number of keystrokes as possible.
- The output should look as follows,

  [image]

  where all spaces are well balanced, all equal signs are well aligned, the horizontal line exists to show the process of subtraction or addition, the sign of the process can be changed to either plus or minus, and the vertical lines are tall enough just to separate the left and right equations (no excessive vertical line).

How is the most elegant way to get such a diagram?

Comment: Note that I used MS Paint to edit my original output such that it becomes the ideal output I want to achieve. That is why there is no code for the ideal output.

Comment: What about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cUTbV.png) instead?

Comment: Here's [version 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fbDke.png)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An elementary `array` implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{}l@{\quad}l@{\quad}r@{}l@{}c}
    3x + 2y & {}= 7  & \xrightarrow{\times 3} & 9x + 6y & {}= 21  \\[\jot]
    9x + 8y & {}= 22 & \xrightarrow{\phantom{\times 3}} & 9x + 8y & {}= 22 & ~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$+$}} \\
    \cline{4-5}
            &        &           &    - 2y & {}= -1  \\[\jot]
            &        &           &       y & {}= 1/2 \\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

One can play with the rule length in or to reduce the overhang on the right. For this, perhaps use `\rlap{$-1$}` and `\rlap{1/2}`.

Comment: The best answer but not the perfectest one. :-)

Comment: I didn't understand, why the solution with redundant keystrokes (\smash,\raisebox, .8\normalbaselineskip, &=, \xrightarrow, & &, etc. which have to type the *user*, is signed as best one. What is bad about \gem macro?

Comment: @wipet: I could write that in a macro also, if you wish.

Answer (score 5):

From the question doesn't follow that LaTeX is necessary but ``the coding must use as minimal number of keystrokes as possible''. So I suggest the following solution with minimal external resources and without LaTeX:

```
\input opmac

\def\gem{%
   \def\tabiteml{$\enspace}\def\tabitemr{\enspace$}
   \adef={\kern-1em&{}=}
   \def\0{\phantom0}
   \def\grule##1{\multispan3&\multispan2\hrulefill
      \tmpdim=-.2pt \advance\tmpdim by\fontdimen22\textfont2
      \lower\tmpdim\rlap{ \ $##1$\phantom+}\cr}
   \def\result{&\omit&\omit&}
   \table{rl|c|rl}
}    
$$   
\gem{
  3x + 2y = \07  & \times3 & 9x + 6y = 21 \cr
  9x + 8y = 22   & \times1 & 9x + 8y = 22 \cr
  \grule -
  \result -2y = -1 \cr
  \result y = 1/2
} 
$$
\end
```

Now, you can run the command pdftex document.

---

May17: I rewrote my solution without using opmac only by basic TeX commands. So the macro code is more mysterious but the user can use exactly the same macro \gem as above. It will work in LaTeX too.

```
\def\gem{%
   \lccode`\~=`\= \lowercase{\def~}{&{}=}
   \catcode`\==13
   \def\0{\phantom0}
   \def\grule##1{\multispan3&\multispan2\hrulefill
      \dimen0=-.2pt \advance\dimen0 by\fontdimen22\textfont2
      \lower\dimen0\rlap{ \ $##1$\phantom+}\cr}
   \def\result{&\omit&\omit&}
   \def\myhalign##1##2{\vcenter{\halign{##1\cr##2\crcr}}}%
   \myhalign{\hfil$##$&$##$\hfil\quad\strut\vrule&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\quad\vrule
            &\quad\hfil$##$&$##$\hfil}
}
$$
\gem{
  3x + 2y = \07  & \times3 & 9x + 6y = 21 \cr
  9x + 8y = 22   & \times1 & 9x + 8y = 22 \cr
  \grule -
  \result -2y = -1 \cr
  \result y = 1/2
}
$$
```

Note that the \gem macro needs minimal number of keystrokes from all solutions mentioned here and it outputs *exactly* the result given in the question.

Comment: Where can I find `opmac`?

Comment: @morbusg: In TeXlive or google "olsak opmac"

Answer (score 4):

Here, I use `tabstackengine` features to build some useful macros that will allow for a compact syntax you desire.  One could, of course, reduce the keystrokes further by `\let`ting things like `\alignLongunderstack` to shortcuts like `\aLus`, etc.

Note that, if one of the `\times` multipliers requires two or more digits, that particular stack will be left-aligned by my aesthetic interpretation, though the alignment can be changed with the optional argument on `\Longunderstack` in the definition of `\multsimeq`.

REVISED to handle added case commented on by OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\solveop[1]{\smash{\protect\raisebox{-.4\baselineskip-2.5pt}{${}#1{}$}}}
\newcommand\multsimeq[2]{%
  \,\,\stretchleftright{\vert}{\,\Longunderstack[l]{\times #1\\ \times #2}\,}{\vert}}
\def\xlu#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1{}$}\setbox1=\hbox{$\,\,$}%
  \stackunder[.4\baselineskip]{#1{}}{\protect\rule{\wd0+\wd1}{.5pt}}%
}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}\def\stacktype{L}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[
  \alignLongunderstack{
    3x + 2y =& 7\\
    9x + 8y =& 22
  }
  \multsimeq{3}{1}
  \alignLongunderstack{
         9x + 6y = & 21\\
    \xlu{9x + 8y =}& \xlu{22}\solveop{-}\\
              -2y= & -1\\
               y = & 1/2
  }%
\]
\[
  \TABbinary
  \tabularLongunderstack{lcr}{
    2x - 5y &=& 2\\
    10x  &=& 5
  }
  \multsimeq{5}{1}
  \tabularLongunderstack{lrcl}{
         10x&\!\!{}-{}25y&=&10\\
    \xlu{10x}&\xlu{\,~~~~~~} &\xlu{\,=}& \xlu{~\,5}\solveop{-}\\
              &{-}25y&=&5\\
              & y&=& -1/5
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The use of the math environment `\[...\]` is optional in this MWE, because the solution is composed solely of stacks and stretches.  The `\stackMath` directive will force all stacking commands to process their arguments in math mode.  Likewise, `scalerel` macros process arguments in math by default.

Comment: The shortcoming of this answer is when for example we have `2x - 5y =2` and `10x = 5`, the alignment becomes no longer well positioned.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Please see revision.

Comment: It is more complicated than Werner's.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with at first:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}{align*}
            3x +2y =7  \xrightarrow{\times 3} 9x +6y           &=21 \raisebox{-0.3cm}{\makebox[0.2cm]{\hrulefill}}\\         
            9x +8y =22 \xrightarrow{\phantom{\times 3}} 9x +8y &=22                                               \\[0.5em]
                                                           -2y &=-1                                               \\
                                                             y &=\nicefrac{1}{2}
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But then I realised that this isn't really the optimal solution for several reasons:

1. This layout confuses the reader as to what direction represents time - sometimes it's to the right and sometimes it's downwards. It would be better if there were a way to consistently move through iterations of the solution such that it is obvious by following the page how the equations changed before they were solved.
2. This layout limits your ability to annotate each step because at some points more than one formula is on the same line. Obviously this is not a concern with such a simple piece of maths, but if the idea is to scale up to harder things then this could prove unhelpful in the future.
3. This layout is not easy to set well, and looks bad when set less than well.
4. For similar reasons as 2, it is hard to label either of the formulae because there are other elements both in their X and Y axes.

I spent less time on this alternative, but I think it will serve your needs better.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}{align}
\nonumber &\text{A}      &\text{B}                                               \\
  3x + 2y &= 7 & 9x + 8y &= 22             &\text{The question}                  \\
  9x + 6y &= 21& 9x + 8y &= 22             &\text{Formula A $\times$ 3}          \\
       6y &= 21& 8y      &= 22             &\text{Cancel 9$x$ from both A and B} \\
          &    &       2y&=1               &\text{Formula B $-$ Formula A}       \\
          &    &        y&=\nicefrac{1}{2} &\text{Checkmate}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly based on Werner's answer, Mico's answer and Herbert's answer scattered around this site. I display here the final code just for sharing purpose. Therefore, wiki is attached to this answer such that I will not receive any reps.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs,array}

\newcolumntype\specifier{%
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{\quad}c@{\quad}
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{}c}

\newcommand\act[1]{\xrightarrow{\quad\mathclap{\times #1}\quad}}
\newcommand\ope[1]{~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$}}}
\newcommand\equ[3]{{}#1 & {}#2 & {}=#3}

\begin{document}
$
    \begin{array}{\specifier}
     \equ{3x}{+3y}{7} & \act{1} & \equ{3x}{+3y}{7}            \\[\jot]
     \equ{3x}{}{22}   & \act{3} & \equ{3x}{}{66}   & \ope{-}  \\\cmidrule{5-7}
         &&           &         & \equ{}{{{-3y}}}{59}         \\[\jot]
         &&           &         & \equ{}{y}{-59/3}            
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Feel free to edit it. And I wish there will be a new package developed for this question.