# How to increase the horizontal space in an array below?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\specifier{%
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{\quad}c@{\quad}
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{}c}

\newcommand\action[1]{\xrightarrow{\quad\mathclap{\times #1}\quad}}
\newcommand\operator[1]{~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$}}}

\begin{document}
$
    \begin{array}{\specifier}
    3x  & {}+ 2y    &  {}=7     & \action{1}    & 3x    & {}+ 3y    & {}= 7  \\[\jot]
    x   &           &  {}=22    & \action{3}    & 3x    &           & {}= 66 & \operator{+} \\\cline{5-7}
        %&           &           &               & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{25mm}{1pt}}  & $+$\\
        &           &           &               &       &        3y & {}= -59  \\[\jot]
        &           &           &               &       &         y & {}= - 59/3 \\
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

I want to increase the space of

[image]

such that it becomes as follows. The red line shows the space I mean.

[image]

How to increase the horizontal space in an array?

Comment: Up to now I still don't understand why we have to write  mathematical expression with array as shown above where each term must be separated to get proper alignment. It makes the writing look unnatural. A smart package should be developed.

Comment: Well, I thought I gave you more natural syntax at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-get-a-diagram-showing-elimination-method-to-solv/178505#178505 `:^)`, but you chose to go with the `array` approach `8^b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\cline`, you could use `\cmidrule` of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. The added bit of vertical spacing provided by `\cmidrule` may just suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}

\newcommand\specifier{%
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{\quad}c@{\quad}
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{}c}
\newcommand\action[1]{\xrightarrow{\quad\mathclap{\times #1}\quad}}
\newcommand\operator[1]{~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$}}}

\begin{document}
$
\begin{array}{\specifier}
3x  & {}+ 2y  &  {}=\phantom{0}7 & \action{1} & 3x & {}+ 3y    & {}= \phantom{-0}7  \\[\jot]
x   &   &  {}=22   & \action{3}  & 3x    &  & {}= \phantom{-}66 & \operator{-} \\
\cmidrule{5-7}
        %&           &           &               & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{25mm}{1pt}}  & $+$\\
        &           &           &               &       &        3y & {}= -59  \\[\jot]
        &           &           &               &       &         y & {}= - 59/3 \\
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\specifier{%
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{\quad}c@{\quad}
        r@{}r@{}l
        @{}c}
\newcommand*\xstrut[1][3ex]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% default 3ex

\newcommand\action[1]{\xrightarrow{\quad\mathclap{\times #1}\quad}}
\newcommand\operator[1]{~\smash{\raisebox{.8\normalbaselineskip}{$#1$}}}

\begin{document}
$
    \begin{array}{\specifier}
    3x  & {}+ 2y    &  {}=7     & \action{1}    & 3x    & {}+ 3y    & {}= 7  \\[\jot]
    x   &           &  {}=22    & \action{3}    & 3x    &           & {}= 66 & \operator{+} \\\cline{5-7}
        %&           &           &               & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{25mm}{1pt}}  & $+$\\
  \xstrut     &           &           &               &       &        3y & {}= -59  \\[\jot]
        &           &           &               &       &         y & {}= - 59/3 \\
    \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]