# How to get curly brace, alignment and separator line in the same equation?

Tags: math-mode, positioning, brackets

[image]

Hi,

I already know how to get curly brace and alignment.

```
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
8x + 6y &= 4 \\
-15x - 6y &= -3
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]
```

The problem is how to draw separator or sum line and how to continue alignment with side note.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us some code you already have. It is saving a lot of time for us. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here I do some stacking.  I had to introduce `\xlu` to achieve underlining on tabbed fields.

EDIT: I create `\twobrak[text]` as a stackable 2-row bracket element, that can be incorporated into the tabular stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\xlu#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{}$}%
  \stackunder[.4\baselineskip]{#1{}}{\protect\rule{\wd0}{.5pt}}%
}
\newcommand\twobrak[1][]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\mbox{#1}\ttwobrak}}
\savestack\ttwobrak{$\left\{\Centerstack{\\}\right.$}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[\TABbinary
  \tabularLongunderstack{rrl}{
            8x&        + 6y = & 4\\
    \twobrak\xlu{-15x}& \xlu{{}- 8y =}& \xlu{-3}\\
           -7x&           =   &  1\qquad\qquad\vert:(-7)\\
              &           x = & {-}1/7
  }%
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted a [hybrid-]right alignment on the last column, then try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\xlu#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{}$}%
  \stackunder[.4\baselineskip]{#1{}}{\protect\rule{\wd0}{.5pt}}%
}
\newcommand\twobrak[1][]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\mbox{#1}\ttwobrak}}
\savestack\ttwobrak{$\left\{\Centerstack{\\}\right.$}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \[\TABbinary
      \tabularLongunderstack{rrrl}{
                8x&        + 6y = & 4&\\
        \twobrak\xlu{-15x}& \xlu{{}- 8y =}& \xlu{-3}&\\
               -7x&           =   &  1&\qquad\qquad\vert:(-7)\\
                  &           x = \rlap{$-1/7$}& &
      }%
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Based on my answer at [What is the most elegant way to get a diagram showing elimination method to solve simultaneous equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-get-a-diagram-showing-elimination-method-to-solv/178505#178505)

---

Follow up:

The introduction of `\twobrak[]` allows a larger stack with multiple bracketed elements in a single stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\def\xlu#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{}$}%
  \stackunder[.4\baselineskip]{#1{}}{\protect\rule{\wd0}{.5pt}}%
}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\newcommand\twobrak[1][]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{\mbox{#1}\ttwobrak}}
\savestack\ttwobrak{$\left\{\Centerstack{\\}\right.$}
\begin{document}
\[\TABbinary
\tabularLongunderstack{rrll}{
x        & - 2y =         & 13              &                \\
\twobrak[some text] 3x       & + y  =         & 4 \qquad\qquad  & \vert ~\cdot 2 \\
         &                &                 &                \\
x        & - 2y =         & 13              &                \\
\twobrak[more text]\xlu{6x} & \xlu{{}+ 2y =} & \xlu{8}         &                \\
7x       & =              & 21 \qquad\qquad & \vert:7        \\
         & x =            & 3               &
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and very quick response! This really helps me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
  \begin{blockarray}{r@{}r@{{}={}}l@{\qquad}l}
    \begin{block}{\Left{\scriptsize\fcolorbox{IndianRed3}{white}{\parbox{1.6cm}{\raggedright Here, we can add some explanations}}}{\{\,}r@{} >{{}}r@{{}={}}l@{\qquad}l}
      8x & +6y & \hphantom{-}4\\
      -15x & -6y & -3\\
    \end{block}
    \cmidrule[0.6pt](l{0.66em}r{2.8em}){1-3}
    -7x & {}& \hphantom{-}1 &\lvert\colon (-7)\\
    & x &-1/7
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following uses a default `array` construction to lay out the elements you require:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{r@{}r@{}l@{}l}
    \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{$
      \left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array}\right.
    $}
    &   8x + 6y & {}= 4 \\
    & -15x - 6y & {}= -3 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & -7x \phantom{{} + 6y} & {}= 1 & \qquad (\div -7) \\
    &         x & {}= -\frac{1}{7}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The layout choices in the code is particular to this case, and would probably require more work in the event that some of the numerals should change.

A change in `\arraystretch` is to match (to some extent) the vertical spacing of `align`-and-friends.

Answer (score 0):

I edited Steven's submitted code:

```
\[\TABbinary
\left\{\Centerstack{\\}\right.\raisebox{3.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{
\tabularLongunderstack{rrll}{
x        & - 2y =         & 13              &                \\
3x       & + y  =         & 4 \qquad\qquad  & \vert ~\cdot 2 \\
         &                &                 &                \\
x        & - 2y =         & 13              &                \\
\xlu{6x} & \xlu{{}+ 2y =} & \xlu{8}         &                \\
7x       & =              & 21 \qquad\qquad & \vert:7        \\
         & x =            & 3               &
}}
\]
```

One more question. How do I get curly left side braces for the first two equations?

Comment: Please post a follow-up question as a new question. You can add a link to this question with answers.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz advice is the proper advice.  However, in this case, I will edit my answer here respond.

Comment: Please see my follow-up revision that addresses the case you mention here.